# c# open another form from current form button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, winforms, desktop-application

I want to open another form on button click and it is image viewer form and i want to enter data on first form  with reference as second form but not working, all controls are there on second form itself even in minimization , after closing that form only allowing to enter data on first form.

Comment: Can you please specify what you have tried

Comment: It would be awesome if you can provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: An example code would be good, but I guess your issue is the form is shown as a dialog, call Form.Show() instead of Form.ShowDialog()

Comment: special thank you  Shameer A Mohammed my issue is resolved with Form.show()

Comment: special thanks to  Shameer A Mohammed my issue is resolved with Form.show() instead of Form.ShowDialog()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to open a new form from button click of another form then you can do it like this.

```
 //Will be called on button click
 buttonClickEvent()
{
   NewForm objectForm = new NewForm();
   objectForm.Show();

}
```

This will bring other form in foreground. 
If you are having another query then please try to share some codes as well as try to add more details on what you have tried and what you expect

Comment: thank yo so much subham  it got resolved with .show()